# Is there a way to group parameters into command in Linux?

Tags: linux, bash

I know that in Linux I can do this:

```
$> cat file.txt > total.txt
```

and I do understand that the following is the same thing:

```
$> cat < file.txt > total.txt
```

as cat basically copies whatever in stdin into stdout

so I was wondering if the following:

```
$> cat file1.txt file2.txt > total.txt
```

can be done in this way :

```
$> cat < file1.txt file2.txt > total.txt
```

but it turns out that only file1.txt is redirected into cat
so is there a way " like parenthesis" to group the parameters of cat or any other command ??
as in :

```
$> cat < (file1.txt file2.txt) > total.txt
```

Comment: `cat <(cat file1 file2)` is the only thing I can think of. But of course it is useless.

Comment: Why would you ever want to do this?

Comment: since cat copies whatever in stdin into stdout 
i would like to think of it as such only , without having to memorize its other use which is 
    cat file1 file2 ...
having a single abstract and pattern-compliant  way of thinking about commands is very important 
so bases on the concept that cat copies whatever in stdin into stdout i want to use:
    cat file1 file2 > total

this way:

    cat <  file file   > total

Comment: Note also that many commands accept the files as parameters normally, without you having to use the indirection `<`.

Comment: "since cat copies whatever in stdin into stdout i would like to think of it as such only" - **don't**. what's the point? it doesn't do anything.

Comment: i know that @fedorqui but that's why i want to use < as to find a fundamental and atomic way of using such commands 
without having to have to representation of the command in my mind

Comment: `zsh` has a feature close to what you want; if you set the `MULTIOS` option, you can write `cat < file1 < file2`. But this fundamentally change what `cat` thinks it is reading from. It does not know it is reading from two separate files, but just a single pipe supplied by the shell.

Comment: Note that IO redirections are *not* command parameters; they are handled by the shell and essentially invisible to the command they are used with.

Comment: Note also that passing as stdin to a command that accepts files will often cause it to behave differently or lose functionality. There isn't an atomic way of doing things.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to send the contents of a set of files as an input to a command that reads standard input you can use a pipe, e.g:

```
cat file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt | wc -l
```

Let's say you have some utility that only knows how to read files, but does not work with standard input. You can do something like this:

```
not-stdin-smart-util <(cat file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt)
```

In this case `cat` can be replaced with anything that produces standard output, using files or not. As was observed in a comment, this method does have restrictions on the seek operations. It will also not work if the utility is reading the file with `mmap()`.

Comment: If it accepts files, you could always, i dunno, try just passing the files to program...

Comment: @123 The results will not necessarily be the same, though.

Comment: The `<(...)` example also only works if `not-stdin-smart-util` doesn't need to seek backwards in its input.

Answer (score 0):

If there are only txt files

cat *.txt > output_file

Any limitations using this? Or did I get you wrong?

Comment: that works only if you want to concatenate ALL the files in a directory  or at best if all the files you want to concatenate have name resemblance

Comment: Need not be. In bash, we can do this:                                                             shopt -s extglob                                                                                        and then provide any exclusion commands